# Laravel 5.6 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on GET request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a custom Request class which deals with the validation of a form. This form uses 'GET' and will filter down all the results the User can see on the page.

My rule for the start date:

`'date_start' => 'nullable|date|required_with:date_end',`

is causing a message:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

My controller looks like this:

```
public function index (ApprovedSubmissionsFilterRequest $request)
{

    ...
```

I believe that this is because when the validation fails, it sends a GET request back to the index method, which once more fails the validation and redirects back to the index method etc. etc.

How do I avoid this loop? I do not want to use a POST request instead of a GET.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('formSubmission', 'FormSubmissionController@index')
 ->name('formSubmission.index');
```

Thank you.

NOTE (edit):

Not all validation errors cause this - it only seems to be the `required_with` that is causing the issue. Somebody has mentioned it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19589) previously.

Comment: nothing to do with validation, it has to do with the URL you are trying to access when it has an error

Comment: You might need to customize the handler, see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L248. Or customize the response given by the ValidationException: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L230

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in my project, and cannot reproduce the problem. So do you really use the correct validation rule, because from the docs, the `required_with` takes an effect only if the other field that you are trying to validate exists in the request. So in your case `date_start` should not be present in the request and `date_end` should exist in order for this validation to take place:

> **required_with:foo,bar,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

- Also from the github issue that you have mentioned, you can debug in the exception handler what happens when `ValidationException` is thrown
- Your last note, have you tried with all validation rules except that one if it passes?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to force the message to come up by only entering 1 out of the 2 dates. The other validation rules work successfully (e.g. if I change `nullable` to `required`, it will redirect back with the error message) which is why I am most confused. I will take a look in the exception handler but it seems like strange behaviour to me. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: i would recommend creating a custom Rule class and writing your own logic!